# Aptly command is unable to open database

Tags: apt

I'm currently running an apt repo with aptly.
However, today my repo wasn't working.
When i tried running this :

`aptly repo list`

the command didn't succeeded and showed :

`Unable to open database, sleeping 11.058056147s, attempts left 10...`

Where does this error come from and how can i fix this ?

Edit :
Stack overflow thinks i do not show enough debug details.
Also I've resolved my problem so see the answer for the solution

So i currently have an aptly server and I'm using the CLI at the same time.

PS :
As it has been pointed out to me, this thread should best be elsewere.
I exported it to here : https://superuser.com/q/1652881/1390494

Comment: "Stack overflow thinks i do not show enough debug details"—I don't think this is off-topic because it lacks debugging details, but it _is definitely_ off-topic since it has nothing to do with programming. It might be on-topic on [su] or [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se].

Comment: Oh i see, you are right. Thanks !
That's too bad there is no "aptly" tag for apt repo management

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research, it appears that the problem was a previous aptly process which has crashed but was still holding locks.
Killing it fixed the problem

Edit :

This solution was only temporary as the problem occurred again some time after killing the process.
The problem was the aptly api running concurrently with the CLI.
As the doc says https://www.aptly.info/doc/api/ i should run the api with `-no-lock` flag to have both API and CLI running.